# connecting new kannel box to opensmppbox

Tags: kannel, opensmppbox

i have been trying to connect a new box (17.x.x.x)which i just installed kannel on it. i already have a running kannel on another box (19.x.x.x) which can send sms and recieve. i  installed opensmppbox on the 19.x.x.x . when i start opensmppbox it shows waiting for incomming connections. then when i start kannel on the 17.x.x.x it connects to the smsbox but gives an error connecting to the opensmppbox. i have spend too ling a time on this.

how can i solve this problem. here is my kannel.conf for the 17.x.x.x

```
# Core 
group = core
admin-port=9000
wapbox-port=9001
smsbox-port=9002
admin-password=Wass
status-password=Wing
dlr-storage=mysql
log-file="/var/log/kannel/bearerbox.log"
log-level=0
access-log="/var/log/kannel/access.log"
access-log-clean=true
access-log-format="%t %l [SMSC:%i] [SVC:%n] [ACT:%A] [BINF:%B] [FID:%F][from:%p] [to:%P] [flags:%m:%c:%M:%C:%d] [msg:%L:%b] [udh:%U:%u]"
box-allow-ip="*.*.*.*"
unified-prefix="0234,+234,00234"

#######################################
# WAPBOX box 
group = wapbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/wapbox.log"

#######################################
#SMSC group - For 38276
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = smppbox
host = 192.101.17.30
port = 2775
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = "hot"
smsc-password = "kkkk"
interface-version = 34
system-type = 
my-number=38260
msg-id-type = 0x03
alt-charset = GSM
#denied-smsc-id = 
#source-addr-ton = 0
#source-addr-npi = 0
#dest-addr-ton = 0
#dest-addr-npi = 0
allowed-prefix-regex = ^\+?(0|234)((8[01]2)|(808)|(7[01]8))

#######################################
# SMSBOX
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = localhost
smsbox-id = vsmsc
sendsms-port = 9009
sendsms-url = "/cgi-bin/sendsms"
global-sender = cingular
reply-couldnotfetch = "Could not temporarily get content...please try again"
sendsms-chars = "0123456789 +-"
http-request-retry = 1
reply-emptymessage = ""
http-queue-delay = 30
max-pending-requests = 1000
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox.log"
log-level = 0
access-log = "/var/log/kannel/smsbox-access.log"

#######################################
# DATABASE
group = mysql-connection
id=mydlr
host=localhost
username=root
password=Wind
database=inm
max-connections=1

group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = dlr
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc

below is the opensmppbox.conf

#
group = core
dlr-storage = internal

group = opensmppbox
opensmppbox-id = smppbox
opensmppbox-port = 2775
bearerbox-host = localhost
bearerbox-port = 9000
log-level = 0
log-file = /var/log/kannel/opensmppbox/opensmppbox.log
our-system-id = 
use-systemid-as-smsboxid = true
route-to-smsc =Singtel
smpp-logins = "/etc/kannel/smpplogins.txt"
#route-to-smsc = emitsms

group = mysql-connection
id = mydlr
host = localhost
username = root
password = Wing
database = inm
max-connections = 1

group = dlr-db
id = mydlr
table = dlr
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxcid

below is the smpplogins.txt

system-id-01 password-01 system-type-01
client-02 password-02 vma 127.0.0.1
client-03 password-03 vma *.*.*.*
hot cingul12 vma 17.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

in opensmppbox change bearerbox-port to smsbox-port of core group in kannel conf ie change 9000 to 9002 in opensmppbox conf